# Design: 2 Entities (both have same abstract parent class) in UITabViewController

Tags: ios

Okay so the title isn't very clear - sorry I couldn't find a good way to express what I'm trying to accomplish.

So here's my setup - I have an Abstract CoreData class, call it `Parent` that has `name` and `photo`. I then made `Child1` and `Child2` that inherit from `Parent`.
I want to have a `UITabViewController` that has 2 tabs: `Child1` and `Child2`, and each tab's `UIViewController` will have a `UITableView` to display only `name` and `photo` (so just the properties in the Abstract Base Class).

What would be the best way of doing this? The "Easy" way to do it is just disregarding the Abstract Base Class and create 2 different `UIViewController`s for the `UITabViewController` tabs, have a `NSFetchedResultsController` for each, and have a lot of duplicate code.
But there *must* be a better way to approach this right?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, for anyone interested...
I have my `Parent` abstract base class with its 2 child classes `Child1` and `Child2`.
I created a generic `UIViewController` meant to hold a `Parent` entity called `ParentUIViewController`:

```
var entity: String { get { return "Parent" } }
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<ListObject> = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Parent>(entityName: self.entity)
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
        managedObjectContext: self.context,
        sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
        cacheName: nil)

    frc.delegate = self

    return frc
}()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // do stuff with fetchedResultController
    // fetchedResultsController.object(atIndex: IndexPath) has a "name" and "photo" attribute so I use them 
}
```

Then I just created 2 other `UIViewController`s and all I had to do was

```
class Child1VC: ParentUIViewController {
    override var entity: String { get { return "Child1" } }
}
class Child2VC: ParentUIViewController {
    override var entity: String { get { return "Child2" } }
}
```